# Retrieve the dynamical link text using Selenium

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Goal:
Select the second link, from top, by using `By.LinkText`

```html
<a class="ng-binding" href="#/test/id_var1">324  fff</a>
<a class="ng-binding" href="#/test/id_var2">44 gggg</a>
```

Problem:
In this context the link text `44 gggg` is not static because the link text changes every time the page is refreshed.

My idea is to retrieve all `class="ng-binding"` and then use the second link as a `linkText,` but I don't know how do it?

Comment: U can use cssSelector here if u wish

Comment: Do you always want the 2nd one? How do you know which one is the right one if the link text changes each time? Is it always the "id_var2" one or ???

Comment: The text of the second one can be change

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simply that it is impossible. You cannot get an element by link text if this text is dynamic and you don't know the value.

You could select it using other methods though.

css-selector

```
a[class='ng-binding']
```

tag-name (not recommended as it is probably not unique)

```
a
```

class-name

```
ng-binding
```

xpath

```
//a[@class='ng-binding']
```

Find the elements in a list and pull out the one you need.

Another option is selecting the 2nd element immediately using xpath.

```
(//a[@class='ng-binding'])[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

use the below as cssSelector:

```
a.ng-binding[href$='/test/id_var2']// this will return the second link.
```

if u want to get all the elements using the

```
ng-binding
```

class, use the below as cssSelector

```
a.ng-binding//return all elemtns using the ng-binding class
```

Comment: How should I apply the "a.ng-binding[href$='/test/id_var2']" in relation to syntax code LinkText?

Comment: here no need to use link text use as CurrentDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("a.ng-binding[href$='/test/id_var2']"));

Comment: @noor That doesn't answer his question though. The asker specifically asked for By.LinkText

Comment: @RemcoW why not? as there are a lots of option to locate element, why a user will stuck only in one particular method to locate element, method to find an element using locator is not static.....

Comment: @noor He specifically asked for By.LinkText. I know there is loads of different options and it's good that you mentioned these, but you didn't mention anything about By.LinkText. So the asker asked for A and you give them B, which doesn't make a lot of sense if you don't explain why you didn't go with A.

Comment: @RemcoW there is no A or B, u suggest an approach for A, i suggest an another approach for getting A ... thats all .... thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also use below xpath:

```
 //a[@href="#/test/id_var2"]
```